# How to sort the json object with the object key in android?

Tags: android, json, performance

Since the JSON object is not reliable, when I create a new json object from json text file, the order go wrong. So I decided to re-order the json object.

Correct order (Json file content)

```
{
"211": {
        "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/09\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
        "timestamp": 1386514507,
        "cover": ["15\/Pg015.png",
        "16\/Pg016.png",
        "1\/Pg001.png",
        "2\/Pg002.png"],
        "year": "2013",
        "month": "12",
        "day": "09",
        "issue": "2013-12-09",
        "id": "211"
    },
    "210": {
        "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/08\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
        "timestamp": 1386415087,
        "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
        "2\/Pg002.png",
        "3\/Pg003.png",
        "4\/Pg004.png"],
        "year": "2013",
        "month": "12",
        "day": "08",
        "issue": "2013-12-08",
        "id": "210"
    },
    "209": {
        "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/07\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
        "timestamp": 1386331278,
        "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
        "2\/Pg002.png",
        "3\/Pg003.png",
        "4\/Pg004.png"],
        "year": "2013",
        "month": "12",
        "day": "07",
        "issue": "2013-12-07",
        "id": "209"
    },
    "208": {
        "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/06\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
        "timestamp": 1386255815,
        "cover": ["15\/Pg015.png",
        "16\/Pg016.png",
        "1\/Pg001.png",
        "2\/Pg002.png"],
        "year": "2013",
        "month": "12",
        "day": "06",
        "issue": "2013-12-06",
        "id": "208"
    }
}
```

......

Incorrect order (When I create a JsonObject)

```
{
"211": {
    "id": "211",
    "timestamp": 1386514507,
    "cover": ["15\/Pg015.png",
    "16\/Pg016.png",
    "1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png"],
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/09\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "issue": "2013-12-09",
    "month": "12",
    "year": "2013",
    "day": "09"
},
"210": {
    "id": "210",
    "timestamp": 1386415087,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/08\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "issue": "2013-12-08",
    "month": "12",
    "year": "2013",
    "day": "08"
},
"195": {
    "id": "195",
    "timestamp": 1385115154,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/23\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "issue": "2013-11-23",
    "month": "11",
    "year": "2013",
    "day": "23"
},
"194": {
    "id": "194",
    "timestamp": 1385048906,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/22\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "issue": "2013-11-22",
    "month": "11",
    "year": "2013",
    "day": "22"
},
"197": {
    "id": "197",
    "timestamp": 1385306370,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/25\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "issue": "2013-11-25",
    "month": "11",
    "year": "2013",
    "day": "25"
}
}
```

.....

I have the incorrect order jsonObject right now. How to create a new json object with the correct order? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON object has no order, it's just a map. Even if you write the JSON in the wanted order in a file, once loaded again it won't have any concept of order.

If you want order, you have to use an array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "211",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": "210",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to put the json fields to an object, one json object one java object, and put it in arraylist<object>. let say I need to sort by object.id, is there any way to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Use a custom Comparator: `Collections.sort(objList, new Comparator<Object>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
           return a1.getId().compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getId());
       }
   });`

Answer (score 1):

you can make the class comparable accordingly (based on id in your case) and then can call Collections.sort(/*list of objects extracted from the Json file*/);

Comment: Thanks, I decided to put the json fields to an object, one json object one java object, and put it in arraylist<object>. let say I need to sort by object.id, is there any way to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Yes, like I said, when you're defining the class, make it implement comparable interface, and override the compareTo(Object another) method on the basis of the Ids of objects. Then the time when you have the arraylist of objects, call Collections.sort(/*your arraylist*/);